# What does swarmmode mean?

Tags: traefik

I'm trying out Træfik, and I'm running it as a service in a Docker swarm mode cluster. I've got a handful of stacks, and each stack runs on it's own overlay network. Træfik sits in front of all these stacks, just like you would do with a good old HAProxy sitting in front of a web cluster.

It works very well withouth `swarmmode = true`. It does not work if I enable swarmmode.

What is it that `swarmmode` does, and should I use `swarmmode` in the described scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It means that traefik will use the service labels for configuration and the container ones.